# How to apply filter to excel with phpexcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a excel created in PHPExcel and I want to filter some data in a excel file, by AUNV (this would be the 'F' column) column. Help!

```
|Date  |Num.Client|Name  |Sales  |UNV |AUNV  |
+------+----------+------+-------+----+------+
| date |    01    | name | $1004 |  0 | 1.00 |
| date |    02    | name | $3003 |  0 | 0.00 |
```

Comment: You need to apply an autofilter.... take a look at the `10autofilter*.php` samples in the `/Examples` folder

Comment: And if i want to order the rows from that without applying a filter

Comment: You'll have to order the rows yourself, or via MS Excel; PHPExcel will not do sorting for you